# Error initiating microSD card in SPI mode

Tags: pic, c, spi, sd, card

I am trying to interface a 32 GB microSD card with [PIC32MX795F512L](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en545660) using SPI communication. SPI communication is working fine as I have tested it by shorting the Data Input and Output line and receiving back the data which I sent. I am following the examples provided in [Lucio de Jasio's book, *Programming 32-bit Microcontrollers in C*](http://blog.flyingpic24.com/programming-32-bit/).

Following are the tasks I am performing:

```
1. Initializing the SPI Communication in initSPI(), setting the baudrate=76 (250&nbsp;kHz)
2. Initializing the SD card
   -> CS = 1
   -> Sending 80 clock cycles to wake the card
   -> CS = 0
   -> Sending CMD0 command (0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x95)
```

But the problem is I am not receiving the `R1` response from the card, instead I am receiving the `0xFF`. Following is the code:

```
#define FCY 77000000UL
#define FPB (FCY/2)
#define BAUDRATE    9600
#pragma config POSCMOD=HS,FNOSC=PRIPLL
#pragma config FPLLIDIV=DIV_3, FPLLMUL=MUL_21, FPLLODIV=DIV_1
#pragma config FPBDIV=DIV_2, FWDTEN=OFF

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <plib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SDI  _RC4
#define SDCS _RA9
#define enableSD()    SDCS = 0
#define disableSD()   SDCS = 1
#define readSPI() writeSPI(0xFF)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TRISAbits.TRISA9 = 0;   // CS as output
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1;   // SDI as input
    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;   // SDO as output
    TRISDbits.TRISD10 = 0;  // SCK as output
    AD1PCFG = 0xFFFF;
    DDPCONbits.JTAGEN = 0;
    OpenUART1( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT, UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (FPB/16/BAUDRATE)-1 );
    disableSD(); //CS PIN INITIALLY HIGH TO DISABLE CARD
    initSPI();
    initSD();

    while(1)
    {

    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void initSPI( void)
{
    SPI1BRG = 76; // FPB/154=250KHZ; (76+1)*2 = 154, so brg = 76
    SPI1CONbits.MSTEN = 1; // MasterEnable
    SPI1CONbits.CKE = 1;   // CKE on
    SPI1CONbits.ON = 1;    // SPI Module ON
}

unsigned char writeSPI(unsigned int b)
{
    SPI1BUF=b; // Write to buffer for TX
    while( !SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF)
        ; // Wait transfer complete
    return(SPI1BUF);
}

int initSD(void)
{
    int i,r,rx;
    int data;

    // Step1: Disable SD card
    disableSD();

    // Step2: Send 80 clock cycles to wake up the card
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        data = writeSPI(0xFF);
    }

    // Step3: Enable SD card
    enableSD();

    // Step4: Send CMD0 command to RESET
    r = sendCMD0();
    disableSD();
    if(r!=1)
    {
        putsUART1("CMD reject\n");
    }
}

int sendCMD0()
{
    int i,r;
    enableSD();

    writeSPI(0x40);
    writeSPI(0x00);
    writeSPI(0x00);
    writeSPI(0x00);
    writeSPI(0x00);
    writeSPI(0x95); //CMD0 Command

    for( i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        r = readSPI();
        if ((r & 0x80) == 0)
            break;
    }
    return ( r);
}
```

Here is [the schematic](https://i.imgsafe.org/b1437cf.png):

[image: The schematics]

I am not receiving the `R1` response. It is stuck at step4 in `initSD()`.

Is there a way I can know if the card has woken up or not after sending 80 clock pulses? After 80 clock pulses, the response from the card is `0xFF`.

Do I need to reduce the clock frequency? Currently it's 250 kHz.

Why is the card not initializing. How can I fix it?

Comment: You could compare to my library on Github ( [header](https://github.com/edeca/Electronics/blob/master/Include/sd_spi.h), [code](https://github.com/edeca/Electronics/blob/master/Include/sd_spi.c) ) and see what the differences are.  I've tested on a decent number of cards to work out edge cases.

Comment: I'll look for the reference (didn't see it yesterday) , but from what I remember SdCards need a hefty decoupling cap - 10uF//100nF close to the holder. Google the following "decoupling capacitor for SdCard" You probably don't need to go further than the google page :-)

Comment: you might want to look at <http://www.microchip.com/forums/m530149.aspx>  which has code, in C, for accessing the chip in SPI mode.   It is way too long to post as an answer, Or I would post it as an answer.

Comment: @user3629249 can you please share the link again. It says internal server error

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/forums/m530149.aspx

Comment: Have u tried another card? Also get rid of all the ints. Use unsigned char or uint8_t everywhere. Also make the UART print the values of r returned so we can see whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks on the surface like an electrical problem

- Try a slower speed to start - you may have excessive capacitance in
  your lines or a slow speed sdCard.
- Are you polling until the card comes ready (see below)
- Can you put a scope on it to check timings, these are critical?
- Try a different SD card, or same card in a working device
- Can you transmit and receive to a different port on same device?
- Can you transmit and receive to a different board using same PIC device?
- Are you using microchip drivers / software libraries?
- Have you got MISO/MOSI correctly wired?
- Are the power requirements met - decoupling caps etc? 10uF+//100nF (some people use 100uF!!)
- Are your output and input pins configured correctly?

At a later stage you may need to check the following - no particular order.

- Check the 'endianness' of your SPI
- Check your CRC
- Double check your protocol

https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/archive/part1_110.pdf

pg 47 says that you need to poll the device until the card comes ready Are you doing this?

Comment: I am using 250KHZ, will definitely try with slower speed. My Micro SD card is 32gb class 10 and is in good working state. PIC32 is also working fine, I have done many other programs on it. I am not using microchip libraries and yes MISO MOSI lines wired correctly. I think we only have to set CS line manually and rest of the lines are set automatically. I have also uploaded the schematic. Please have a look at it. I didnt get `Check the 'endianness'`, can you please explain a bit

Comment: endianness is the jargon for 'do you send MSB first , or LSB first'. Perhaps check your hardware /pin init code, with that given in the microchip libs. Most of my work is with ARM so I unfortunately cant help with PIC specifics for pin speed, pullup/pulldown etc. Try a delay after setting the CS line.

Comment: You mean to say I should add delay after step1 in initSD()

Comment: @user007 yes, and poll it until it is ready at <50ms intervals. see my edits

Comment: I am not polling instead was waiting for response allowing upto 8 bytes delay. I will poll it until its response is 0x01. Thanks

Comment: Is there any response from the card after sending 80 clock pulses

Comment: The driver I use puts a 1mS wait after power_on (chip select) then send CMD8, CMD55, CMD41. It recommend using < 24MHz unless you do a 'high speed switch'. This is SDIO )4 bit) mode. Polling is in the CMDs

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code for making the MISO pin an input pin or for making the SCK pin output. Since you aren't using the SPI library in `plib`, you have to do all the pin initialization yourself. Also, after sending `CMD0`, increase the number of iterations (in your `for` loop) from 8 to 20 (I use 100), to provide enough leeway. Also use this comparison instead:

```
if ((r & 0x80) == 0) 
   break;
return r;
```

Also make `r` an `unsigned char` everywhere.

Comment: Ohh thankyou for suggesting that. I thought after initializing the SPI, all the SDO SDI sck are automatically configured.  Now I'll make SDO & SCK output and SDI as input.

Comment: Why you are using this if condition: `if ((r & 0x80) == 0)` . Can you explain a bit.

Comment: The first bit of the sd cards response is always a zero. So one must check the first bit of any received bytes for a zero. Your original code does roughly the same thing as mine, but i've been using mine for a while with PICs so i figure mine is more reliable :)

Comment: `uint8_t` would be better than `unsigned char`.

Comment: I used your if condition but the card is not responding 0x01. Is there any error in my functions for transmitting data.? Can you pls have a look at it. Is there any other command I can send before CMD0 to check any other things.?

Comment: Can you update the code in your question? After making all the pin inits?

Comment: @TisteAndii I have updated my code.

Comment: Change all your ints to uint8_t. Explicitly make SPICON1bits.CKP = 0.

Comment: Also put SPI1CON = 0 at the top of the init_spi(). And then try another SD card. No other ideas here :(

Comment: Okay I'll put SPI1CON =0 and will try with that. Thanks

Comment: And make the type changes and the CKP assignment

Comment: @TisteAndii I am not that much expert in SD Card programming but when we initialize SPI module, all the relative pins are configured automatically.!

Comment: Only if you are using the peripheral libraries. Those arent being used here. Inspect open_spi.c in the plib and you will see the same pin assignments there. Here, plib isnt being used for SPI